# Encode String to UTF-8 and 7-bit encoding

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I want to encode a string using both 7-bit and Unicode (UTF-8).

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;  
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String originalMessage = "*ABC";
        sevenBitEncoding(originalMessage);
        unicodeEncoding(originalMessage);
    }

    private static void sevenBitEncoding(String originalMessage) {
        char[] ch=originalMessage.toCharArray();
        byte[] bytes = new String(ch).getBytes();
        StringBuilder encodedMessage = new StringBuilder();
        encodedMessage.append("[");
        for(int i=0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            encodedMessage.append(bytes[i] + ",");
        }
        encodedMessage.replace(encodedMessage.length()-1, encodedMessage.length(), "]");
        System.out.println("7-bit  :" + encodedMessage.toString());
    }

    private static void unicodeEncoding(String originalMessage) {
        byte[] bytes = originalMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        // ByteBuffer byteBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(originalMessage);
        StringBuilder encodedMessage = new StringBuilder();
        encodedMessage.append("[");
        for(int i=0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            encodedMessage.append(bytes[i] + ",");
        }
        encodedMessage.replace(encodedMessage.length()-1, encodedMessage.length(), "]");
        System.out.println("unicode:" + encodedMessage.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
7-bit  :[65,66,67]
unicode:[65,66,67]
```

Expected Output:

Since UTF-8 uses base 16 expected value for UTF-8 is 2A. 
https://flaviocopes.com/unicode/

```
7-bit  :[42,65,66,67]
unicode:[2A,41,42,43]
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't call `.getBytes()` without the encoding parameter. Otherwise you'll always get the bytes in your platform's default encoding. I have no idea what your code is trying to do though, the String `*ABC` has the same bytes in UTF-8 and 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: `String.getBytes` uses the platform encoding which is not defined, but I can't think of a single system where it would be 7bit. Also I have no idea what "UTF-8 uses base 16" is supposed to mean, but it's probably a misunderstanding of what unicode is.

Comment: You're really asking "How to express 42₁₀ as 2A₁₆?" This is called *base conversion*. The rest is quite irrelevant.

Comment: Your blog post is mixing things up. It says things like "If the letter A in ASCII was represented with the number 65, using UTF-8 it’s encoded as U+0041.". In UTF-8 it's still encoded as a byte with decimal value 65. It's **unicode codepoint** is `U+0041`.

Comment: To repeat previous comments in my own words, which I hope will be more clear: the 7-bit expected line shows decimal values, the Unicode expected line shows the **same** values in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a lot of unnecessary things such as creating new Strings from the `char[]` of a previous one for no reason, and calling `getBytes()` without a Charset parameter, which is a no-no. You're also confusing bases, and somehow think that "unicode uses hexadecimal" which just doesn't make sense.

Here's how to show the bytes of a String with given encoding (UTF-8 in example).

```
// Values are decimal, not hex
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("*ABC".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF8)));
```

The bytes for `*ABC` are the same in all common encodings, so if you want to see differences you're going to have to find a very exotic encoding, or use characters that are encoded differently (such as accented characters like é, à, ä, ö, å which take 2 bytes in UTF-8).